# Do I need to enable celery beat to activate result_expires?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have django celery up and running.
Do I have something else in order to activate https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_expires or it works already?

I don't have celery beat installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You do not need Celery beat for that. Result expiry is handled internally by Celery and/or the backend you use in your project.

However, keep in mind this:

> Note
>
> For the moment this only works with the AMQP, database, cache, Couchbase, and Redis backends.

> When using the database backend, celery beat must be running for the results to be expired.